# Kubernetes - Unable to initialize control-plane

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes

Can someone please help

I'm getting the following error when I run 'kubeadm init'

```
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.25.0
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.0: output: E0901 16:50:43.675142    4165 remote_image.go:218] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-apiserver/manifests/v1.25.0: dial tcp 34.107.244.51:443: i/o timeout" image="registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.0"
time="2022-09-01T16:50:43-06:00" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-apiserver/manifests/v1.25.0: dial tcp 34.107.244.51:443: i/o timeout"
, error: exit status 1
    [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.25.0: output: E0901 16:53:14.264007    4564 remote_image.go:218] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-controller-manager/manifests/v1.25.0: dial tcp 34.107.244.51:443: i/o timeout" image="registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.25.0"
time="2022-09-01T16:53:14-06:00" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-controller-manager/manifests/v1.25.0: dial tcp 34.107.244.51:443: i/o timeout"
, error: exit status 1
    [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.25.0: output: E0901 16:55:44.364804    4922 remote_image.go:218] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-scheduler/manifests/v1.25.0: dial tcp 34.107.244.51:443: i/o timeout" image="registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.25.0"
time="2022-09-01T16:55:44-06:00" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-scheduler/manifests/v1.25.0: dial tcp 34.107.244.51:443: i/o timeout"
, error: exit status 1
    [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.25.0: output: E0901 16:58:14.769855    5295 remote_image.go:218] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-proxy/manifests/v1.25.0: dial tcp 34.107.244.51:443: i/o timeout" image="registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.25.0"
time="2022-09-01T16:58:14-06:00" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-proxy/manifests/v1.25.0: dial tcp 34.107.244.51:443: i/o timeout"
, error: exit status 1
    [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.4-0: output: E0901 17:03:14.966455    6024 remote_image.go:218] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.4-0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.4-0\": failed to do request: Head https://registry.k8s.io/v2/etcd/manifests/3.5.4-0: dial tcp 34.107.244.51:443: i/o timeout" image="registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.4-0"
time="2022-09-01T17:03:14-06:00" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.4-0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.4-0\": failed to do request: Head https://registry.k8s.io/v2/etcd/manifests/3.5.4-0: dial tcp 34.107.244.51:443: i/o timeout"
, error: exit status 1
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

I'm unable to initialize control-plane, made sure that docker is running.
kubectl, kubeadm is also working.
Does it look like issue on the K8 side, or did I do anything wrong.

Comment: As per the error it seems like its unable to pull the image. Check if you have made any typos in the image name if not check if that image exists. If these two are not the issue then it should be cause you are machine is not able to reach the registry. Check this with ping command

Answer (score 0):

As per output ,it does look like some connectivity issue due to following line  , probably slow or no connectivity

> failed to pull image registry.k8s.io******

can you check the connectivity to image registry with following

```
ping registry.k8s.io
```

You should get the response from server ,If you donot get the response back ,need to troubleshoot for network connectivity

PING registry.k8s.io(2600:1901:0:1013:: (2600:1901:0:1013::)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2600:1901:0:1013:: (2600:1901:0:1013::): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=69.1 ms
64 bytes from 2600:1901:0:1013:: (2600:1901:0:1013::): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=83.9 ms
64 bytes from 2600:1901:0:1013:: (2600:1901:0:1013::): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=83.4 ms

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message

```
[ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.0
```

The images are not getting pulled and hence the ImagePull error is thrown.
You should have internet connectivity from the machine where the initialize command was run.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to migrate from dockershim to other container runtime as its not supported after Kubernetes 1.23.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/migrating-from-dockershim/